# toolStrip to have menuStrip gradient background

Tags: c#, winforms, toolbar, menustrip

I have a form with a menu and a toolstrip at the top. The menuStrip has a nice looking gradient background, how can I get the same effect on the toolStrip control? I know about the RenderMode property but changing this doesn't have the desired result.

[image: toolStrip background]

Comment: Dont think there is a property for that. There is `BackgroundImage` property if you wanted to make a gradiated image for that.

Comment: How do you render your `MenuStrip` so that it has such a `gradient background`? I mean if you know how to render it, how may want to apply the same render on the `ToolStrip` so that the backgrounds of both are identical.

Comment: The menuStrip is a plain menuStrip control with RenderMode set to "ManagerRenderMode", which is the default. I don't know how it's rendered. How would I apply the same renderer to the toolStrip?

Comment: The MenuStrip and StatusStrip have a horizontal gradient while the ToolStrip has a vertical gradient.  It is odd that Microsoft did it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a custom renderer.

```
public class CustomToolStripRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public CustomToolStripRenderer() { }

    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBackground(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //you may want to change this based on the toolstrip's dock or layout style
        LinearGradientMode mode = LinearGradientMode.Horizontal;

        using (LinearGradientBrush b = new LinearGradientBrush(e.AffectedBounds, ColorTable.MenuStripGradientBegin, ColorTable.MenuStripGradientEnd, mode))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.AffectedBounds);
        }
    }
}
```

Then set your toolstrip to use an instance of this renderer.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CustomToolStripRenderer r = new CustomToolStripRenderer();
    r.RoundedEdges = false;

    toolStrip1.Renderer = r;
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work as intended when the ToolStrip contains items with drop-down menus.  The drop-down menu backgrounds will also become gradient painted.